# How are HashTables in GLib Useful?

Tags: c, hashmap, hashtable

I'm familiar with the idea of a hash function but I'm unclear on how GLib's implementation is useful. I'll explain this with an example.

Suppose I have an expensive function that is recursive (somehow) on the positive real numbers in a weird way that depends on number theory (I'm a mathematician). Let's say I have an algorithm that needs to compute the function on some smallish-range of large numbers. Say [1000000000 - 1000999999].

I don't want to call my expensive function one million times, so I start memoizing values recursively. Then at each call I don't need to necessarily compute the whole function from scratch, I can hopefully remember any values of the function on the lower numbers (during my recursing) that I have already computed. Let's assume that the actual total number of calls at that first level of recursion is low. So that there are a lot of repeated values and memoizing actually saves you a lot of time.

This is my cartoony way of understanding why a hash table data structure is useful. What I don't get is how to do this without knowing exactly what keys I'll need in advance.

Since the recursive function is number theoretic in general I don't know which values it will take over and over again. So I'd like to just throw these in a bucket (hash table) as they pop out of recursive calls to my function

For GLib, it would seem that your (key,value) pairs are always pointers to data that you personally have to keep lying around somewhere. So if my function is computing for input x. I don't know how to tell if I've seen the value x before, the function g_hash_table_contains() for example needs a pointer, not the value x. So what's the use!?

I'm still learning so be kind. I'm familiar with coding in C, but haven't yet used hash tables in this language and I'm trying to do so and be adept at it with GLib but I just don't get this.

Comment: The pointers can be dynamically allocated, and the hash table is managing them. You don't have to keep them elsewhere. The same claim you made can be made against linked lists...With the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let me take a dig at it to explain it.
First of all, if we are using hashmap, then we need [key, value] pair for sure as our input.

So as a user of hashmap, we have to be creative about choosing key, and it varies depending upon the usecase.

In your case, as far as I understood, you have a function which works on a range and gives you result. And when calculating, it uses memoization so that results of small problem, which constitutes the bigger problem, can be used.

So for example, your case, you can use string as your key where string will be [1000000009] which may use result of [1000999998] which may further use result of 1000999997 and so on, and you do not find results in hashmap, then you will calculate it and save it in hashmap.

In nutshell, as a user, we need to be creative about choosing keys. 
The analogues to understand is how you would have done, if you have to think about choosing primary key of database.

Another example to think is how you would have thought about solving  fibonacci(n) using the hashmap.